# How to ignore (for recentf) files opened automatically during start-up

Tags: org-mode, start-up, recentf

Some modes, on Emacs start-up, load a lot of files automatically. Example: Org-mode refreshes its agenda by reading every file configured to contain agenda items.

But these "read the file automatically on start-up" operations end up littering the 'recentf' list. How can I configure these modes to **not register a 'recentf' entry when automatically opening a file**?

I'm aware of `recentf-exclude`. That does not address this need: I want 'recentf' to normally include those files. They should be excluded *only* when the Emacs start-up automated procedures are happening.

What I'm looking for is some way to tell Emacs "while processing this sexp, don't register any file opens for 'recentf'" and then I can wrap the (for example) Org-mode initialisation in that.